# How can I test an iPhone application on device without the key

Tags: xcode, ipad, xcode3.2

How can I run my XCode SDK application on my iPad without key and without jailbreak?

(I found a description yesterday, but cant find it back).
This can be with the device connected to my development machine.

(I can afford the $99, but I cant wait for it to arrive)

Comment: Found the link:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/10325-testing-app-iphone-without-developer-key.html

Seems they do it and know what they are doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without program membership and without jailbreak? You can't.